# Netgear XS748T switch not connecting to 100Mbps devices

Tags: switch, netgear-prosafe

I have this 10Gbps Netgear switch (XS748T), but for some reason I can't get it to light up with devices that seem to be 100Mbps. I've tested this with all different cables, devices, and other switches to make sure the devices and cables work. Works well with 1Gbps and 10Gbps, but just not the 100Mbps...

I also have a XS716T switch, which is the same model, just 16 ports instead of 48 ports, and both are fully updated in terms of firmware, and the 16 port 10Gbps switch works just great out of the box with anything I connect it to.

At first I thought this was just a bad switch, and so did the Netgear support guy, to which he approved an RMA, and sent this second switch, except it is acting in exactly the same fashion, leaving me to believe that this might be a configuration issue and not an issue with the switch itself.

I've checked the configuration settings side by side as best I could with the working 16 port and the not working 48 port and can't seem to find any differences between them, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just been looking at the datasheet for those models.

The **XS716T** supports 16x 100M/1G/10G Copper Ports

The **XS748T** does not support any 100M but 44 x 1G/10G so this is your issue and why you are seeing that it works on the XS716T but not the XS748T.

I have found this information [here](http://www.netgear.co.uk/images/Products/Switches/SmartSwitches/10Gigabitsmartswitchseries/XS708T_XS716T_XS728T_XS748T_DS_15Apr16.pdf) on page 2.

Comment: Yup thanks... Now I feel sad. Although I'm not sure I should feel more sad that I missed that or the ~6 Netgear representatives that also missed that.